# NodeJS Lambda function returns null while still waiting for callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Problem: I have a Lambda function written in NodeJS, simplified version below, which is meant to make a post to a specific URL to get a value in the body of the response. Then I'd like it to do something with that value in functionB, however, the function returns null while waiting for the callback from functionA.

Also, I'm new to NodeJS but I have tried to research this as much as I could before turning to you guys for help, if you find a question that this is a duplicate of, please direct me towards it with a little guidance as I may have come across it before without knowing why it's the same as my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  functionA(event.payload, function(err, data) {
    if(data) {
      console.log(data);
      valueB = data;

      functionB(valueB, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
          console.error('Unknown Error');
        } else {
          console.log(data);
          callback(null, successMessage);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Unknown Error');
    }
  });
}

function functionA(payload, callback) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var result;

  // new HttpRequest instance, in the real code storedURL has been set
  xmlhttp.open("POST", storedURL, true);
  console.info("Linking to: ", storedURL);

  xmlhttp.onload = function () {
    console.log('Entering onload function');
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === xmlhttp.DONE) {
      console.log('readyState done');
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        console.log('status 200');
       // console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
        //console.log(data);
        callback(null, data);
      } else {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(xmlhttp.response);
        callback("error in callback");
      }
    } else {
      console.log('error');  
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.send(payload);
}

function functionB(valueB, callback) {
  //Do something with valueB
  callback(null, successMessage);
}
```

Comment: Does the callback get called? You shouldn't expect the function to return anything but so long as the callback gets called then the code has successfully executed.

Comment: Do not see anything wrong with the callbacks I think the problem is in logic or something

Comment: Do any of your error log get hit?

Comment: The callback does not get called. I can see through log messages that it goes a little bit into functionA and then Lambda just finishes without any kind of callback or return from the function or anything. It does not go into the onload function within functionA, it seems to skip it .

Comment: What exactly does it print in the CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda function? Is Lambda killing the function because it exceeded the timeout you configured for it?

Comment: Lambda is not killing the function because of a timeout, it finishes within ~500ms every time. CloudWatch logs are showing me that it goes into FunctionA, skips the onload, gives log messages for every other part of the function, comes back into exports.handler and then CloudWatch says END and gives a requestID

Comment: Is your XMLHttpRequest returning any data and being logged inside the functionA callback?

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working, but one thing to be careful of: `xmlhttp.onload` will not get called for some failed requests such as when the domain can't be resolved. It will just be ignored and you'll see symptoms like you're describing. You might try using `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange()` to makes sure the actual request is working. (or even better, just use the native `http.get()`)